# How does the resurrection of languages work?

Tags: language-revival

I was looking at the Wiki page for the [Manx language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manx_language) when I came across the following chart of *Number of Speakers by year*:

> [image]

The last native speaker died in 1974 but then we can see a resurgence of speakers in 1991. There aren't a lot of details on the [revival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manx_language#Revival) of the language, the Wiki page just simply states that:

> a scholarly revival had begun and a few people had started teaching it in schools.

This also doesn't answer the question of where new native speaker came from.

So, while this is specifically directed at the Manx language, as an example, I'm more curious about how the resurrection of languages work, especially in terms of native speakers dying and having new native speakers come about.

How does the resurrection of languages work?

Comment: You've heard about the miracle of the [Hebrew language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revival_of_the_Hebrew_language)? Excellent case study of how things like that are achieved.

Comment: Note that with something like Manx its only the last *native* speaker who died in 1974; there still would have been a speech community of hundreds. As with any other language, language revival is all about teaching it to kids. And for it to really succeed the prestige of the language needs to increase so that people will want to use it. That's probably the hardest thing to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, the language needs to not be dead the generation before. Even if a language doesn't have *native* speakers, if it is still used by people, it's not dead yet. Those people could have learned from native speakers, or revived it as a non-native language. A few committed people had had a desire to revive their language starting in the 1950s, and so set about recording native speakers of Manx and promoting adult education in the language.

The second thing you need is enough people in the generation before the first native speakers to be committed to raising kids in the language.

Third is an environment where people prefer to use the language being revived. That includes schools where the primary language of instruction is Manx, or popular media in Manx. The people that started in the 1950s did just that, making weekly radio shows, translating and writing new books, setting up a school, etc.

The fourth thing, it gets much easier if there are living languages or organized revivals in languages similar to it. Manx could borrow and adapt material from Irish Gaelic and Scots Gaelic fairly easily, both in terms of teaching material and linguistic innovations (such as, calquing the phrasing for a new term).